# Parameters with Ajax jquery and struts2 interceptors

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, interceptor

I had an Ajax call with jquery method that was working good, but now i have added an interceptor to the action ajax was calling and i cannot receive those parameters n the action
i think that interceptor is blocking all my ajax parameters so.. what can i do  here is my code

Ajax function

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "editLab",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: $('#lab').val(),
            option: $('#option').val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response.name);
        }
    });
```

Action (Before) 
My `alert()` prints the name passed with `data:` parameter

```
@ParentPackage(value = "inter")
@Action(value = "editLab", results = {
    @Result(type = "json", name = "success")})
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
```

Action (Now)
My `alert()` prints null it seems that my interceptor is blocking parameters that i send with `.ajax`

```
@ParentPackage(value = "inter")
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("interceptor")
})
@Action(value = "editLab", results = {
    @Result(type = "json", name = "success")})
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
```

is there a way to get the parameters with the interceptor and then send to my action again?

Interceptor btw

```
public class LoginAdminInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
    }

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        String result = Action.LOGIN;
        Map<String, Object> sesion = actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession();
        if (sesion.isEmpty()) {
            return result;
        }
        if (!((User) (sesion.get("User"))).getProfile().isEmpty()) {
            if (((User) (sesion.get("User"))).getProfile().equals("Admin")) {
                System.out.println("Admin!");
                result = actionInvocation.invoke();
            }

        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ParentPackage(value = "inter")
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef("interceptor"), @InterceptorRef("defaultStack")
})
@Action(value = "editLab", results = {
    @Result(type = "json", name = "success")})
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
```

I think you will need to add the `defaultStack` interceptor reference which contains the *parameter interface* which basically dumps all the request parameters on the valuestack.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem i had to modify my packages but now it works. thank you